# How do you store multiple UIControlState instances in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit, nsuserdefaults

I'm looking to storing multiple instances of `UIControlState` within `NSUserDefaults` on the IOS platform.

Let's say there is a preference panel with various `UIControl` elements, be they `UISlider`, `UISwitch` etc.

Currently I have a loadPrefs function within `viewWillAppear` and a corresponding writePrefs within `viewWillDisappear`.

Rather than adding the code to store the state within `NSUserDefaults` for any future control that I add, is there an easy way to iterate through all the keys in `NSUserDefaults` and set the relevant states accordingly?

Is there a "proper" way of doing this via an `NSArray` or some other collection or is it not worth the time and bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the entire NSUserDefaults stuff as an NSDictionary by using the dictionaryRepresentation method:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys])
{
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful.

Once you start going through all the keys, how do you match them up to the respective UIControl element?

Comment: Well - that depends entirely of you.

Comment: Ah ok, so there is still some manual work involved at that part.

In that case thanks, you've been really helpful.